# how do I convert int32 IP address into octets in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ip, type-conversion

I'm looking for the opposite to this:

```
require 'ipaddr'
ip = IPAddr.new "10.0.2.15"
ip.to_i                      # 167772687
```

I need to pass something like 167772687, and want to get back "10.0.2.15".

This:

```
ip = IPAddr.new 167772687
```

returns the error:

```
IPAddr::AddressFamilyError: address family must be specified
```

How to I specify that I'm passing int32?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the answer:

```
require 'ipaddr'

ip = IPAddr.new(167772687, family = Socket::AF_INET)
ip.to_s   # "10.0.2.15"
```

Comment: Remember that IPv6 is a thing and will be increasingly important to any code you write.